# Can't install MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

already have Apache mysql php installed but cant install Mariadb

```
kwilga@NAFUbu1:~$ sudo apt install mariadb-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.1 (= 10.1.16+maria-1~xenial) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Have you looked at the following two websites? https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/install-apache-mariadb-and-php7-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts  and https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=digitalocean-nyc

Comment: Version of Ubuntu?

Comment: It is a 16.04//

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was wrong? I'm running into the same issue.